# Contact form don't send well

Tags: php, forms, email, send, contact-form

I have a problem when sending data to the contact form. Data is sent to e-mail only if you click many times, but if you tab to move to the button and press enter data is sent immediately. But still fall into the spam.

#### HTML

```
<div id="f1" class="contact_wrapper">
 <form>
  <div id="r2"></div>
  <input type="text" name='rname' id="names" class="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
  <input type="email" name='email' id="eml" class="email" placeholder="Ваше Email">
  <input type="text" name='subject' id="phon" class="contact_number" placeholder="Контактный телефон">
  <textarea name="message" id="masage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input name="" id="button" type="button" value="Отправить" class="submit" onclick="mail2('Радиус-01 Оформить заявку - последняя форма','names','eml','phon','masage','f1','r2')">
 </form>
</div>
```

#### AJAX

```
<script>
function mail2(subject,names,eml,phon,masage,f,rr){
  var names = document.getElementById(names).value;
  var eml = document.getElementById(eml).value;
  var phon = document.getElementById(phon).value;
  var masage = document.getElementById(masage).value;
  var frt = document.getElementById('generator_konr').value;
  var params = {subject:subject,names:names,eml:eml, phon:phon,masage:masage,kon:frt};

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail2.php",
    data: params,
    success: function(data){
      $('#ertretgfdg').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
    }
  });
} 
</script>
```

#### mail2.php

```
<?

### Referals script start
$debug=0;

function writelog($s) {
  global $lf,$debug;
  if ($debug)
    fputs($lf,"$s\n");
}

if ($debug)
  $lf=@fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'debug.log','a');
$t=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$utm='нет';
$term='нет';

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$utmdata='';
writelog("Session started (zakaz.php) at '$t', IP='$ip'");
writelog("REQUEST: ".print_r($_REQUEST,true));
if (isset($_COOKIE['utmdata'])) {
  writelog("Found saved cookie UTMdata");
  $utmdataexp=explode('&',$_COOKIE['utmdata']);
  if (count($utmdataexp)>=2 && !empty($utmdataexp[0]) && !empty($utmdataexp[1])) {
    $t=$utmdataexp[0];
    $utm=$utmdataexp[1];
    $term=isset($utmdataexp[2]) ? $utmdataexp[2] : 'нет';
    $utmdata=$t.'&'.$utm.'&'.$term;
  }
}
writelog("UTMdata is '$utmdata'");

### Referals script end

$phon = $_POST['phon'];
$names = $_POST['names'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$kon = $_POST['kon'];
$eml = $_POST['eml'];
$masage = $_POST['masage'];

if ($names=='' or $names=='Введите ваше имя') {
  echo '<script>$().toastmessage(\'showErrorToast\', "Введите свое имя");</script>';
  exit;
}
if ($phon=='' or $phon=='Ваш телефон' or $phon=='Введите номер телефона') {
  echo '<script>$().toastmessage(\'showErrorToast\', "Введите номер телефона");</script>';
  exit;
}
if ($eml=='' or $eml=='Ваш email' or $eml=='Введите ваш email') {
  echo '<script>$().toastmessage(\'showErrorToast\', "Введите ваш email");</script>';
  exit;
}
if ($masage=='' or $masage=='Ваше сообщение' or $masage=='Введите ваше сообщение') {
  echo '<script>$().toastmessage(\'showErrorToast\', "Введите ваше сообщение");</script>';
  exit;
}


$er=null;
if ($subject=='Выбран конкретный генератор') {
  $ert='Генератор: '.$kon.'<br/>';
}
$body ='
По вопросу: '.$subject.'<br/>
'.$ert.'
Имя: '.$names.'<br/>
Телефон: '.$phon.'<br/>
Мыло: '.$eml.'<br/>
Сообщение: '.$masage.'<br/>
Рекламная площадка:</b> '.$utm.'<br />
Ключевое слово: '.$term.'<br />


';

$email='myemail@gmail.com';

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$em.">\r\n";
if (mail($email, $subject_t, $body, $headers)) {
  echo '<script>$().toastmessage(\'showSuccessToast\', "Сообщение успешно отправлено");</script>
<script>$(".header .sform").delay( 2000 ).slideToggle();</script>';
  exit;
} else {
  echo '<script>$().toastmessage(\'showErrorToast\', "Ошибка, повторите попытку");</script>';
  exit;
}
?>
<!--
```

Comment: Your problem is, that email sent through this form is received and filed as spam? Did I understand that right?

Comment: Using the `mail()` function commonly leads to mails ending up in the spam folder. Research the alternatives. As for your ajax/event problem, provide a bit more debugging and a more concrete description ("click many times", or "tab [...] move [...] button" isn't very concrete).